# How to do performance Tuning?

Tags: jmeter

After getting the result from JMeter. If I need to enhance the performance, as a tester, what I need to do? Can you suggest any site or book for me?

Comment: To answer that question, we'd need to know more about the application you are testing. JMeter can be used to test any kind of application: Web sites, client-server applications, etc., and the applications can be written in any language.

I think what you are asking is how to enhance the performance of your application. To offer suggestions that would be helpful to you, we'd need to know a little bit about the application you want to enhance.

Comment: @Jonathan  This is a Web Application and language is .net. The scenario is like I need to enhance the performance (response time) at a time of high Load and Stress.

Comment: This question has been answered partly here: - https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2546/where-can-i-find-good-jmeter-tutorials